# Why my Nokia 7.1 makes a sound every 30 seconds until I view the notification?

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, nokia-7.1

Since updating to Android 9 (Pie) a few days ago, my Nokia 7.1 makes alert noises every 30 seconds - 1 minute until I view the notification.

I think it has something to do with the Ambient screen notification setting. I used to have it set at "periodically" which is supposed to be every 2 minutes and would previously just illuminate the screen - not make noise. But now, I get a notification noise about every 30 seconds (37 seconds to be exact) until I acknowledge the notification.

I set the Ambient screen notification setting to be "once" and that seems to have resolved the issue of getting the notification sounds, which is why I believe that setting is no longer working properly.

I can live with that workaround for now, but it really would be ideal to have my screen light up every 2 minutes without noise in the many cases that I don't see it the first time.

I have seen a similar issue reported with a solution of "Tap your Settings, scroll down and tap accessibility, scroll down and tap notification reminder." but I **do not** have that setting.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer an issue since the last Android P update - the setting in question that wasn't working no longer exists.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Still an issue on Nokia 5.1 plus. Settings looks the same with the screenshot, but turning on "New notification" brings the ambient display on and notification sounds every 2 minutes, if we don't dismiss the new notification.

Comment: Considering the phone has no notification light, this is probably a "feature". But they really should give an option to just wake the screen once / when the new notification arrives only (instead of waking it, and ringing a sound, every few minutes)